# How to resolve the diamond issue in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, diamond-problem

I have searched for solutions to the diamond problem but the only one I have found is using [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which I can't use in my case, so I'm asking here to see if anyone has an alternative solution.

I have a base class `Controller` (I cannot change this class) and have two subclasses `SecurityController` and `DevController`. Each of these subclasses introduces methods which also use methods inside the base class. I then have a final class `ApplicationController` which, ideally, would extend both `SecurityController` and `DevController`. Of course, this isn't possible in PHP (single inheritance only).

So my question becomes - what would be the best way to resolve this? I came across *traits* but then realised that doesn't work as the 2 subclasses (which I thought might suit traits) both need to extend `Controller` to access methods inside it. The only other alternative I can see is forcing `SecurityController` to extend `DevController` (or vice versa). Although this works it is not ideal as these two classes come from separate modules which I was hoping to create as *a drop in and use as is* type of plugin.

[This post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/multiple-inheritance-mixin-class) on code review looks promising. An alternative would be good though - I feel I'm likely to introduce errors when trying to improve upon that code.

**Note about the solution**

The accepted answer is still the best way I have found to resolve this issue in general. However, in this case I was able to use traits. I had a method in `SecurityController` called `beforeExecute($dispatcher)` - by changing it to `beforeExecuteTrait($controller, $dispatcher)` and making `SecurityController` a trait then having `ApplicationController` extend `Controller`, use `SecurityController` and adding a method in `ApplicationController` as

```
public function beforeExecute($dispatcher)
{
    return $this->beforeExecuteTrait($this, $dispatcher);
}
```

and by applying the same logic to `DevController` I achieved the desired behaviour.

Comment: As I said in the question - I have done, but the two classes which would suit traits (`DevController` and `SecurityController`) need access to methods in `Controller`. If a trait could extend a class that would be perfect...

Comment: Awesome, @JohnConde, somehow I had no idea about PHP Traits. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could benefit from [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection). In other words, you would instantiate the other classes and then inject those instances into your main class for you to use. This avoids any messes with inheritance in PHP.

```
class A extends B {

}

class C {
    /** @var \A */
    protected $classa;

    public function __construct(\A $class) {
         $this->classa = $class;
    }
}

$a = new \A();
$c = new \C($a);
```

Comment: Excellent! I've been using the Phalcon framework which makes heavy use of this but it never occurred to me to use it here. I'll try that now, thanks!